# Blazor WSAM AADB2C90077 User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of None

Tags: c#, .net-core, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a Blazor WASM dotnet 7 application integrated with Azure AD B2C for the authentication.

After the refresh token is expired, the page is navigating to the B2C login page and the B2C is returning the following error.

> error=interaction_required&error_description= AADB2C90077 User does
> not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value
> of None

I went with default session expiry time, token expiry time and refresh token expiry time in the custom policy.

Can someone please advise to resolve this issue?.